# cannot remove 'folder': Device or resource busy

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile, centos7

I create centos with docker and After I start the container, I would remove a directory where there are other two directories.

and I do :

```
rm -f -r ./folder
```

and I obtain:

```
cannot remove 'folder': Device or resource busy
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: maybe you are using `tmux` and in some other part there is something blocking you from removing

Answer (score 7):

Another pretty much simple answer is following:

**1. Close all your terminal windows (bash, shell, etc...)**

**2. Start a new terminal**

**3. Execute your command again** e.g.:

```
rm -f -r ./folder
```

**4. done**

Hopefully it helps others!

Comment: Closing all my git-bash terminals did the job for me!

Answer (score 3):

if you use windows, it's com.docker.backend.exe , terminate it, everything will ok.

If you know the reason why backend cause this problem, tell me.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. The directory I was trying to remove was setup in the "volumes" section, in one of my docker-compose files.

The directory and docker installation were on WSL and Docker for Windows was connecting to it for easier administration.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, until I closed the code editor VS-Code. Somehow VS code had the folder open so it could not close until the editor was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have that folder opened up somewhere. Try `lsof` to find the opened folder and then `sudo kill <pid>`. Afterwards,  I believe you can remove the folder from there.

Comment: running lsof doesn't show this folder as being open

Answer (score 0):

1- ps aux | grep docker.

From there you can get all processes containing "docker" word

2- #kill *<process_id>*

3- #rm -rf *<thedir>*

Comment: I have windows and this doesnt work for me.. what should be the command for me ?

Comment: I guess you should use "task manager" to kill=stop the processes related, then delete the folder.